# How do you replace a whitespace into a &nbsp; in a <ol> by using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, whitespace

How do you replace a whitespace into a **&nbsp ;** in a ordered list by using jquery?

```
<ol id="selectable" class="ui-selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">a</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee" style=""> </li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">t</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">e</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">s</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">t</li>
</ol>
```

*the row :*

```
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee" style=""> </li>
```

Should be like

```
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee" style="">&nbsp;</li>     (or $nbsp;$nbsp;)
```

does someone know how I can solve this by telling: .ui-widget-content    if whitespace than $nbsp ... ?

Kind reguards

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('#selectable li').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;'));
    });
```

Comment: This will fail as soon as there is more than one space in the text.

Comment: This is better. Note that `/\s/` will also match line feeds, carriage returns and tab characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.ui-widget-content").contents().each(function () {
  if (this.nodeType == 3) {  // 3 == TEXT_NODE
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/ /g, String.fromCharCode(160)) );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check wheather the text value is empty by trmming data and checking lenght

if the lenght is zero than you sould provide html content as  `&nbsp;`

```
$('li.ui-widget-content').each(function() 
{   
    if(($.trim($(this).text()).length==0)
       $(this).html("&nbsp;");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#selectable > li').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text()==" ") { //you're looking for 'space'
            this.innerHTML="&nbsp;";
        }
    });

});
```